# why event is undefined in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, firefox

Here is my javascript code

```
 function filter(id, e) {
      if (!e) e = window.event;
      $(e.target).closest('.item').addClass('hidden'); 
      ...    
      ...    

 }
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <div onclick='filter(1)'>Testing</div>
```

In Chrome , this function is work , but in Firefox.

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

Comment: Should be `window.Event` instead of `window.event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

It is simply not a thing implemented by Firefox. It's not an issue with your code's logic.

Comment: thanks , i changed the function to click function and it works!!